# Filter a view displaying nodes of one type using a user entity reference field on that node

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have a vocabulary (*Countries*) listing all countries. I added an entity reference field to the User entity (*Nationality*) referencing the *Countries* vocabulary. To the *Article* content type, I added:

- An entity reference field (*article_countries*) for the *Countries* vocabulary
- An entity reference field (*article_owner*) for the users

Currently:

- Every user created on the site has the *Nationality* field set to a taxonomy term value related to *Countries*
- Every article created on the site has the *article_countries* field set to a taxonomy term value related to the *Countries* taxonomy vocabulary as well as the *article_owner* field set to a user
- I have also created a view displaying the *Article* nodes as below:

[image: View Display]

The view is displaying all articles for which the *article_countries* is equal to the nationality of the currently logged-in user.

I want to add an exposed filter to filter the list of articles basing on the *article_owner* value. The filter must only contain all *article_owners* values referring to users for which the nationality is equal to the nationality of the currently logged-in user.

Finally the view will be similar to below screenshot.

[image: View Display with filter]

Comment: As side note, since nodes already have a field for the node owner, what is the purpose of adding another field for the node owners?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thought someone will ask such logical question ! There is no any purpose and this is not the real case, `article_owner` field is a replacement of the real field but client asked to not expose any information publicly.